# Difference between Windows driver uninstall functions

Tags: windows, driver, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall a driver with C#. I'm calling unmanaged code and came across these three different Windows API functions that seem to do the same thing.

```
DiUninstallDevice
SetupUninstallOEMInf
DriverPackageUninstall
```

What is the difference between them?